# eslint strange error when using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, eslint

I got this warning from eslint, I'm using create-react-app.

```
./src/components/auth.js
  Line 24:  Unexpected labeled statement                                           no-labels
  Line 24:  'authenticated:' is defined but never used                             no-unused-labels
  Line 24:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

And I think I don't have any problem with my component below, it's so annoying

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        this.props.history.replace('/login');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        this.props.history.replace('/login');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  return connect(state => {authenticated: state.auth.authenticated})(Authentication);
}
```

I've no clue what should be fixed, first time using eslint.

Comment: HI Madeline please show your .eslintrc or package.json (if you used that method to store your eslint configuration.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing this, javascript is confused.

It is seeing an arrow function that is returning the instruction `authenticated: state.auth.authenticated` which is a wrong instruction.

---

You can write either :

```
connect(state => ({ 
     authenticated: state.auth.authenticated,
}));
```

We add parenthesis to tell javascript that this is not an instruction but a json.

Or

```
connect((state) => { 
   return {
     authenticated: state.auth.authenticated,
   };
});
```